# ajax not loading on first click

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here's my problem.

I have some link that trigger ajax function to load the content in a div. It working fine in Chrome and FireFox. However there is an issue in IE.It react funny. If i click on a link for the first time since the page is loaded it wont work as expected. It will load on the second click or if i mouse over the area that should be updated. And only IE react like that.

```
My Javascript function to query data 

function req_frame(box,user,action,product) {
var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

         if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
    parent.frames[user].document.getElementById(box).innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
        }

    };

    var sVar1 = product;
    var sVar3 = encodeURIComponent(user);
    var sVar2 = encodeURIComponent(action);


    xhr.open("GET", "ajax_http.php?variable1=" + sVar3 + "&variable2=" + sVar2 + "&variable3=" + sVar1, true);
    xhr.send(null);

}
```

I know this code is working cuse well it is! even tho the var are a lil mixed up

And i call this function using event triggering with Jquery like that

```
$("#ajphoto").live('click', function(){ req_frame("framebox","contpic","ajphoto","product"); })
```

Anyone wana help? Thanks

Comment: Why not use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ??

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function req_frame(box,user,action,product) {
  var result = $(parent.frames[user].document.getElementById(box));
  result.load("ajax_http.php", 
    {variable1:user, variable2:action, variable3:product});
}
```

Comment: this look good but i dont want to rewrtie the entire thing! i will check it out tho. Hum im not a JS expert but is that a callback using Jquery? if so how do i include jquery in my own js file?

Comment: thanks for your vote, Zero G. You must have been including jQuery already, because you used `$("#ajphoto").live('click', function(){ req_frame("framebox","contpic","ajphoto","product"); })` before. Anyway, easy way to include jquery is to put `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'></script>
` in your <head> section